# android webview contents not selectable

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, selectable

I have a webView. WebView shows html with text, images, buttons etc.
I want to make few things.
1) That user can not select text in webView
2) The same behavior of click and long click by button.

I made next things for resolve my problems:
First of all, I added to html page style:

```
body {
     ...
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -webkit-touch-callout: none;
     ...
}
```

But it didn't help me. This solution didn't work on all androids.
So I tried to add touch listener to webView.
 Code of listener:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    private float prevX;
    private float prevY;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        boolean handled = true;
        if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {
            prevX = event.getX();
            prevY = event.getY();
        } else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
            if (Math.abs(event.getX() - prevX) < 50
                    && Math.abs(event.getY() - prevY) < 50) {
                handled = (event.getEventTime() - event
                        .getDownTime()) > 200;
            }
        }

        Log.d("-------------------------------------------------", ""+handled);

        return handled;
    }

});
```

But this didn't work either, may be I made something wrong?
After that I tried to add long click listener:

```
webView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        v.performClick();
        return true;
    }
});
```

This solution solves only the first problem.

So, where did I go wrong?

Comment: do you want that your webview should not be clickable or anythng else?? please elaborate...

Comment: I want that webview should be clickable, but some of parts of html page should not be clickable. I don't want that user can make copy of parts of text in html page. But in html page I have inputs and buttons...

Comment: Thanks for corrections of errors in grammar...

Comment: Well you will have to use a web view client for this. You willl have to override the web view client in order to get the click events. If you want i can give you the sample code..@@

Comment: Yes, I would like to see the sample code...thanks.

Comment: From a user point of view, there is nothing more frustrating than not being able to copy-paste text from a web page. Flash driven websites are especially frustrating in this aspect. Why do you want to make the text not selectable? It's not going to stop anyone who really wants to copy it.

Comment: @AntonCherkashyn It's not your place to question why.  It's to say you know how to do what he wants to do, or keep quiet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `addJavascriptInterface();` of WebView. Create an inner class of Activity. The class is an interface between android and Your Jscript. You have to use Jscript for this.